# Choose on which monitor new windows appear in KDE

Tags: kde, window-management, multi-monitor, kwin

I am using KDE on Debian Jessie.

Whenever I open an application, it appears on the first (left) screen. How do I change this?

This happens with most applications. For example Vuze opens correctly on the monitor it has been before, but Double Commander (doublecmd) which I use heavily doesn't.

If it matters I have 3 screens. Left: FullHD TV (HDMI) + middle: QHD monitor (DisplayPort) + right: FullHD laptop display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that only a handful of applications, including Double Commander, does show up on the non-primary left screen, on which mouse cursor is not. That would suggest an error in those applications, rather than a problem with window manager settings. I will contact such developers.